# Get all Geometries Openlayers3

Tags: javascript, openlayers

Wondering if anyone knows how to get multiple geometries of what a user has drawn on an openlayers 3 map.

At the moment i am using

```
        var coords = feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates();
```

Is there a openlayers method to get the geometries of all the polygons/points etc. drawn?

hope that makes sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you use a vector layer to place the geometry objects a user has drawn (lines, points, polygons etc)
Then you need to call:

`var feats = vector.getSource().getFeatures();
    //You have a Collection of features
    console.log("feats",feats);
    //now you may iterate through your features
    feats.forEach(function(feat){
    //and you may get the coordinates for each individual feature
    var coordinates = feat.getGeometry().getCoordinates();
    });`

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p_tsagkis/nw35pthr/) to demostrate. 
Draw some vectors on the map and then press the "get all features" button

Comment: Thanks for the reply man! I managed to get it working just before but in a different way for anyone interested as well. I had the coordinates saving to a variable. So decided to use an array to store all the point the user had click, on each new press it would add the point to the array. Not at a computer but can post code later if anyone interested.